# ScreenShot issue in ARKit in swift

Tags: swift, arscnview

i have application that uses ARSCNView. i'm trying to take a screenshot on click of a button and saved that image in the gallery. But when i take a screenshot it does not show the content on that screen. Just show that image, i have some labels on it but it does not show that in an image. This is my code,

```
  @IBAction func captureImage(_ sender: Any) {


 image = sceneView.snapshot()
     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

How can i show that labels and buttons on ARSCView in a screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`snapshot()` will only take screenshot of Scene.

To take screenshot of Scene with Labels and Buttons use below method:

```
 func snapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.isOpaque, 0)
        self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let fullImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        guard let image = fullImage, let rect = rect else { return fullImage }
        let scale = image.scale
        let scaledRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x * scale, y: rect.origin.y * scale, width: rect.size.width * scale, height: rect.size.height * scale)
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: scaledRect) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .up)
    }
```

To Take Screenshot:

```
 @IBAction func takeScreenShotTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let screenShot = snapshot(of: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

If you want to take screenshot of fullscreen then just call `snapshot()`.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: how should i run this function on click of my button? @ivarun

Comment: let me try . @ivarun

Comment: the x, y, width and height in the function call is not showing whole image. @ivarun

Comment: If you want fullscreen screenshot then call `snapshot()` without cgrect.

Comment: will it than show the labels and buttons also? @ivarun

Comment: yup now got that. perfect